# Difference of two sets generated from different collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Assume here are two collections in MongoDB.

The first collection `Goods` includes the following documents

```
{
    {_id: Object(), Id: "a", Type: "daily"},
    {_id: Object(), Id: "a", IsSale: true, Price: 20},
    {_id: Object(), Id: "b", Type: "monthly"},
    {_id: Object(), Id: "c", Type: "daily"},
    {_id: Object(), Id: "c", IsSale: true, Price: 30, Origin: "Canada"},
    {_id: Object(), Id: "d", Type: "daily"}
}
```

The second collection `Status` includes the following documents

```
{
    {_id: Object(), Id: "a", SoldOut: false}
    {_id: Object(), Id: "a", SoldOut: true}
    {_id: Object(), Id: "c", SoldOut: false}
}
```

I want to get an `Id set` in which `Type = "daily"`, the status `IsSale = true` (these information can be found in collection `Goods`) and the `Id` good has not been sold out (this information can be found in collection `Status`).

Specifically, from collection `Goods`, we can get the Id set `{"a", "c"}` where `Type = "daily"` and `IsSale = true`. From collection `Status`, we can get the Id set `{"a"}` where the good is sold out (there is a `SoldOut=true` document in `Status`). Thus, the result is the difference of the two set `{"a", "c"} - {"c"} = {"a"}`.

I know it is not common to perform such difference operation in MongoDB, I still try to figure out the problem instead of solving them in Service logic because it can help reduce the Response time.

Can u give any suggestion? THX.

Comment: In `Status` collection `{"Id" : "a"}` is a duplicate with two `SoldOut` values. How to you decide is `true` or `false`. Why are there a duplicates?

Comment: @ArsenDavtyan Aha, that's decided by our demand. We want to track the status of whether the good is sold out every 1 min, so in `Status` collection, u will see many duplicate items for a specific `good Id`. Actually, I remove some columns in `Status` for describe the problem easily, so u may be confused of this collection. : )

Comment: Then, what's you criteria to check which record from `Status` collection to fetch? As per current structure, there is no way to find out `Id` is Sold out or no.

Comment: @ArsenDavtyan As long as there is a `SoldOut=true` in `Status` collection, it means the `Id` is sold out. And here we can ensure `Id` in `Status` is a sub set of `Id` in `Goods` collection where their `IsSale = true`.

Comment: Or just ignore the `status` collection, is there a query method getting the `Id` set from the `Status` collection where `Type="daily"` and `IsSale=true`? In this example, this query should return `Id` set {"a", "c"} .@ArsenDavtyan

Comment: There is a way to do this with `aggregate`? Is that acceptable for you? ?

Comment: Yeah, we can use aggregate here. But I'm not sure how to write the query correctly, can u show me an example? THX @ArsenDavtyan